# Android Beacon - Trouble with passing beacon to function

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, beacon, altbeacon

I'm trying to pass the closest beacon to a function to launch an activity but I'm not getting good results. I'm able to pass it to the function but it never reaches the point where it launches the activity since everything gets called back to the `didRangeBeaconsInRegion`

```
beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
        for(Beacon beacon : beacons) {
            if(!beaconList.contains(beacon)) {
                beaconList.add(beacon);
            }
        }
        handleBeacons(beaconList.get(0));
    }
});
```

Addtl Info: In the function all I'm doing is trying to compare the beacon's ID to a certain ID I have. If it matches, I launch an activity.

Comment: Can you please show the `handleBeacons` method definition?  Are you sure that method is being called?

Comment: Able to pass the beacon now, but I'm having a problem with the activity since it just overlaps from one to the other. How should I go about this?

Comment: Sorry, that sounds like a different question.   Perhaps you should post a new one -- if you do, you should post the code and explain what is no behaving as you expect so we can help you.